# segment fault when i push back element on vector class in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class HasPtr {
private:
    int *count;
    string *str_ptr;
public:
    string getStrPtr(){
        return *str_ptr;
    }
    HasPtr(const string &str = string()) : count(new int(1)), str_ptr(new string(str)) {
        cout << str << endl;
    }

    HasPtr(const HasPtr &hasPtr) {
        count = hasPtr.count;
        str_ptr = hasPtr.str_ptr;
        *count = (*count) + 1;

    }

    HasPtr &operator=(const HasPtr &hasPtr) {
        if (this == &hasPtr) return *this;
        if (--*count) {
            delete str_ptr;
            delete count;
        }
        count = hasPtr.count;
        str_ptr = hasPtr.str_ptr;
        (*count)++;
    }

    bool operator<(const HasPtr &hasPtr) {
        return this->str_ptr < hasPtr.str_ptr;
    }

    ~HasPtr() {
        if (--*count) {
            delete str_ptr;
            delete count;
        }
    }

    friend void swap(HasPtr &ptr1, HasPtr &ptr2);
};

inline void swap(HasPtr &ptr1, HasPtr &ptr2) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(ptr1.count, ptr2.count);
    swap(ptr1.str_ptr, ptr2.str_ptr);
    cout << "swap" << endl;
}

int main() {

    vector<HasPtr> vecArr;
    HasPtr hp1(string("a"));
    HasPtr hp2(string("d"));
    HasPtr hp3(string("c"));
    HasPtr hp4(string("b"));

    vecArr.push_back(hp1);
    vecArr.push_back(hp2);
    vecArr.push_back(hp3);
    vecArr.push_back(hp4);

    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<4-i-j;j++){
            if(vecArr[j] < vecArr[j+1]){
                swap(vecArr[j],vecArr[j+1]);
            }
        }

    for(auto e : vecArr){
        cout<< e.getStrPtr() <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code is pasted above. In the code, I define a class and corresponding copy operation, assignment operations and so forth.

when the program executes the statement below

```
   vecArr.push_back(hp3);
```

segment fault happens in my machine. I am newbie in C++. the question has confused me for several hours. I don't know why. please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running your program in a debugger? Hopefully it will tell you exactly which line causes the segfault.

Comment: thx for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unlink logic is broken:

```
    if (--*count) {
        delete str_ptr;
        delete count;
    }
```

which deletes if `--*count` is true ie not equal to 0. So proper condition should be:

```
    if (not --*count) {
        delete str_ptr;
        delete count;
    }
```

also you should not duplicate that code but move it to a method and call from dtor and assignment operator.

Comment: I have accept your suggestion to extract the same code part.

Comment: @chbchb55 it is actual operator http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative and you can use either

Comment: @chbchb55 you are wrong again :) There is section "Compatibility with C" on that page - it works with a header

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems.  The first is that the guard around the deallocation is negated.  As written, this would deallocate the shared space every time that a copy occurred.  Change the `if (--*count)` lines to `if (--*count == 0)` to fix that.

The second is that the assignment operator does not `return *this`.  With a return value, chained assignment operations (e.g., `a = b = c`) will not work as expected.